# Is it possible from one button to reset a page? HTML

Tags: html, forms, radio-button, reset

I've created a html page and in that page I have forms, drop down lists and radio tags and tables. from one button I wanted to reset everything on the page when its clicked upon.

Comment: You could just navigate to the same page again when you click the button. That should reset everything.

Comment: @user3630455 what do you mean with reset tables?

Comment: i have default values there so when the page first loads up the default value is 0 until the user easers it and changes it to a different number

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following JavaScript method to clear the HTML input file control's value:

```
function clearFileInputField(tagId) {
    document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML = 
                    document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML;
}
Or, if refactored in jQuery, this should work as well:

$("#control").html($("#control").html())

Or, for textbox type
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var ii=0; ii < elements.length; ii++) {
  if (elements[ii].type == "text") {
    elements[ii].value = "";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a reset button, please refer to this page for more information -> [LINK](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.reset.html)

But if you have multiple form on the page you can write a javascript function to reset all of them like this:

```
$('#yourResetButton').click(function(){
    $('form').each(function(idx, obj){ 
        obj.reset();
    });
});
```

You could also refresh your page as stated in other answers but in my opinion that could be very disappointing for your users to see that the page is refreshing

A little [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a82b81ej/2/) as example

Comment: There is no reset for jquery object.

Comment: @Vladimirs yes, completely forgot. Thank you!

Comment: still will not reset the tables mentioned in the question

Comment: @overflowed how table can be resetted at all?

Comment: With a page reload, or manually by restoring the state the table had on page load, but too less code visible to know how to that

Answer (score -1):

You can reset with [reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset) however you won't be able to reset your inputs that doesn't included into forms, otherwise you can clear inputs within your forms like:

```
$('form').each(function (index, obj) { obj.reset(); });
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/s9Ugr/178/)

Comment: Question was to reset everything on that page not only a particular form

Comment: @overflowed wrong comment, it should be "I am down-voting because you down-voted me". And fyi down-vote on your question wasn't by me and also being greedy for reputation is very bad =P

Comment: Your answer doesn't match the question, to reset a whole page. That's all, Cirou answer still only refers to forms, but he at least wrote to iterate over all forms, and if I would be that greedy on reputation I would just delete my answer.

Comment: His code won't even work as $('form').reset(); will result in JavaScript error =)

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type="button" onclick="function() {window.location.href = window.location.href;}" name="Reset" value="Reset">
```

Comment: How many places you seen where form cleared with page reload? =-)

Comment: @Vladimirs ...all of them?

Comment: @Juhana haha never seen. link please

Comment: @Juhana omg, what exactly? So you say google does relaod page when you clear form?

Comment: It's a way to reset a site, it doesn't matter how popular that is. It's a correct answer.

Comment: @Vladimirs No, I'm saying Google clears the form when you reload the page. You're thinking it the wrong way around.

Comment: ok but how would i reset the table, (the table includes things where the user would enter stuff in)  also how would i reset the dropdownlist

Comment: @Juhana ok I see, but I asked about actual example of that, where and who in that world reload page in order to clear few inputs?